# Fully Android Backup without root

Tags: backup, android, restore, root, tablet

We're using a general Android Tablet (Chinese Made) is it possible to fully backup the whole tablet including apps, settings, app data, etc. And restore them on other tablets without rooting the devices. Please advise me with the right software.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of... but not really.

If you're willing to dig into the [android software development kit](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) and learn to use `adb` then there are some commands like `backup` and `pull` that can be used to pull the applications and settings from your device down to your PC.  There's already a good answer for this question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) that details the process well.

However, in my experience, these backups are somewhat incomplete because they depend on the application developers having **allowed** you to backup information for the app by setting the [appropriate flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup) when they compiled the application.

And, there seems to be little rhyme or reason in many cases as to why they don't want you to backup their information using the development tools.  For example, I have a podcast app that prevents backups - despite the fact that they have their own in-app backups.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried the ADB backup however all I'm getting is a 1Kb file so basically it's not a correct backup of the whole system to be restored on other devices. As well when rebooting in recovery mode I don't see a backup option there I'm not sure if the tablet is configured to disallow backup and if there's a way to enable it.

Comment: You're definitely missing something in your configuration or ADB commands.  Even if most of your apps don't permit ADB backups, I'd guess a good portion of the system apps would.  In any case, you should be getting more than 1Kb backed up.  What kind of output do you get from your adb command?

Comment: .ab is the file extension. I tried the command adb backup -apk -shared -all -system -f backup08262012.ab

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I was actually wondering if you got any text output from the command when you ran it.  You are running that from a command prompt I assume?  Does anything show up on your device when you run the command?  Is USB debugging enabled?  Is the screen unlocked when you run the command?

Comment: Everything is enabled and unlocked and unfortunately no output at all

Comment: When I boot in recovery mode I don't see the backup option all I can see is apply update from ADB or internal storage or external storage or cache plus wipe cache partition or wipe data/factory reset

Comment: You should not be trying to backup from recovery mode.  You should be backing up from a normal boot.  If that's not working using the instructions from the answer I linked to, I'm kind of at a loss.  Perhaps you need to download the platform tools for the specific version of Android running on the tablet, but this has never been a problem for me in the past - of course I haven't backed up using this method in about a year either.